# Geoviews - Plot heat map using tabular data

Tags: holoviews, pyviz, geoviews

I have point data in the following tabular format (3 columns, any number of rows):

| Latitude | Longitude | Temperature |

How can I interpolate values to get a heat map like this:

[image]

Instead of point data like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Trimesh](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/TriMesh.html) for this, but it won't extrapolate values around the edges, so your plot won't cover the entire region unless there are data points along the edge.